# SWAT Team Concealing Identity

Tags: united-states, police

What gives SWAT team members legal cover to conceal their identities by wearing balaclavas or similar?

Comment: Why do they *need* legal cover to do that? In many places, you're generally allowed to conceal your identity.

Comment: Some jurisdictions do have laws against wearing masks in public; see http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13756/can-i-legally-wear-a-facekini-in-us-beaches.  Such laws likely have provisions that exempt law enforcement personnel executing their duties.  You'd have to look up each specific law to know for sure.  So I'm close voting this as "too broad" until it's narrowed to a specific jurisdiction.

Comment: But no jurisdiction that I know of has a generic law against wearing masks: the prohibition is always relative to the intent to violate the law in some way.

Comment: The same one that allows kids to wear masks on Halloween

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [web site](http://www.anapsid.org/cnd/mcs/maskcodes.html) has collected up a number of state anti-mask laws. It is useful to know that the purpose of the tactical balaclava is face protection. The anti-mask law of California prohibits mask for escaping identification in the commission of a public offense; Florida likewise limits it to criminal-like conduct and some sketchy "equal protection" situations (presumably anti-Klan legislation). Georgia generally prohibits masks but takes the tack of listing exceptions, including "traditional holiday costumes" and "for safety reasons". In Louisiana it is prohibited to wear a mask to conceal identity, but there are enumerated exceptions, including Halloween and Mardi Gras (no surprise), or for religious reasons; we can assume that if Lousiana SWAT teams wear tactical balaclavas, the legal basis is face-protection.

It would appear that in Minnesota, SWAT team members cannot wear a mask until winter:

> A person whose identity is concealed by the person in a public place
>   by means of a robe, mask, or other disguise, unless based on religious
>   beliefs, or incidental to amusement, entertainment, protection from
>   weather, or medical treatment, is guilty of a misdemeanor

In New York, the anti-mask law seems to be subsumed under [loitering](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/penal-law/pen-sect-240-35.html), which includes

> Being masked or in any manner disguised by unusual or unnatural attire
>   or facial alteration, loiters, remains or congregates in a public
>   place with other persons so masked or disguised, or knowingly permits
>   or aids persons so masked or disguised to congregate in a public
>   place;  except that such conduct is not unlawful when it occurs in
>   connection with a masquerade party or like entertainment if, when such
>   entertainment is held in a city which has promulgated regulations in
>   connection with such affairs, permission is first obtained from the
>   police or other appropriate authorities;

which could be narrowly construed to outlaw wearing of balaclavas by SWAT teams (they are masked, they congregate and remain in public with others masked men, it is not in connection with entertainment.